# when click on element through automation using diff. click methods its gives undefined could not be loaded but if clicked manually it's working

Tags: java, selenium

In selenium script when click on particular element through automation using diff. click methods its gives "undefined could not be loaded" error message pop-up but if clicked manually it's working.
After closing the error pop-up if clicked again through automation won't work but manually its working.
tried by:

- increasing wait
- checked element visibility and is the element is clickable before click method
- Actions class click method
- refreshed the browser before click

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you share the page that you are trying this on? What are you trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

You never find elements in Selenium and start clicking on them. In Selenium there is an an object called `WebDriverWait` that waits for specific conditions like element is clickable, visible or part of the DOM.

```
// set wait timeout to a maximum of 10 seconds 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);    
WebElement we = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
elementToBeClickable("By.Css or By.Xpath");
we.click();
```

If that doesn't work - try again with the child or parent element of the element you are trying to click on. Or, maybe just close the pop-up via the automation before you click.